# How to use python to scan and communicate with BLE device under Windows environment

Tags: python, windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm a newbee for python. I searched a lot on website trying to find a way to scan and communicate with BLE device under Windows environment using python, however, almost all the results are under Linux or Android environments. The reason why I ask this question is because I already made a test architecture using python on windows, what I need is just to add a new test case for testing bluetooth LE device into my architecture. Any suggestions will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: This [link](http://christopherpeplin.com/2015/10/22/pygatt-python-bluetooth-low-energy-ble/) might help.

Comment: Use the [PyGATT](https://github.com/peplin/pygatt) module.

Comment: Thanks!! Will have a try.

Comment: That works！I only want to return something that I found to help other freshmen like me. First you need to buy a BGAPI dongle if you want to connect with BLE device on windows through python. After plug your BGAPI dongle, you can try the following python code:            
import pygatt ||
adapter = pygatt.BGAPIBackend() ||
adapter.start() #start your dongle ||
adapter.scan() # you will get a result of nearby ble devices || 
device = adapter.connect(’xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx’)#input the device address  you want to connect to ||

Answer (score 6):

[Bleak](https://github.com/hbldh/bleak) is a Python package that supports BTLE on (not only) Windows. I tested the following code from the project page (after installing it with `pip install bleak`):

```py
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakScanner

async def run():
    devices = await BleakScanner.discover()
    for d in devices:
        print(d)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(run())
```

It successfully lists the discovered Bluetooth devices. Examples on how to connect are included in the [Bleak project documentation](https://bleak.readthedocs.io).