# Automate a bluetooth connection on Windows

Tags: windows, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to automate the connection of a device running linux with my Windows PC. On the device side, I'm able to automate the connection using 'expect' in bash. On windows, I downloaded Bluetooth Command Line Tools to attempt to automate the PC side. I was able to pair with my device using the friendly name of the device, however I did need to manually accept a prompt in Windows that asked me whether a Pin on my device matched the pin in the prompt. The terminal on my linux device did indeed show the same pin, so I clicked 'matches', and then was able to pair the device.

I tried to configure Windows Bluetooth service not to alert me when a new connection comes in, but when I change that, I am just unable to pair in this case. When I start a pairing session from the Windows PC, it just hangs indefinitely.
Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do from a Windows PC, or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this myself, but you can maybe try and use Bleak for what you want. According to the website:-

> One can use the BleakClient to connect to a Bluetooth device and read
> its model number via the asynchronous context manager like this:

```
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakClient

address = "24:71:89:cc:09:05"
MODEL_NBR_UUID = "00002a24-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"

async def main(address):
    client = BleakClient(address)
    try:
        await client.connect()
        model_number = await client.read_gatt_char(MODEL_NBR_UUID)
        print("Model Number: {0}".format("".join(map(chr, model_number))))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        await client.disconnect()

asyncio.run(main(address))
```

You can find more relevant information here:-

- [How to use Python to scan and connect to BLE devices in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43418193/how-to-use-python-to-scan-and-communicate-with-ble-device-under-windows-environm)
- [Bleak - Bluetooth Low Energy platform agnostic kit](https://bleak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)
- [Bleak examples](https://github.com/hbldh/bleak/tree/master/examples)
- [How do I connect to a Bluetooth device on Windows using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72616707/how-do-i-connect-a-bluetooth-device-to-windows-with-python)